# sql server function that indicates if previous query returns results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a function in TSql that indicates whether the previous query returned any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`@@rowcount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

```
--# your query goes here

if @@rowcount > 0 or rowcount_big() > 0
begin
  --# query returned something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you stated what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you thinking about queries within the same connection or in the same batch or last query run on the server?  Are you referring to queries within a single database?  There is a variable @@rowcount that has the number of rows of the last command executed, that is  a likely candidate, but it depends on the context.